# Laravel Eloquent: Using ->update(), just update if it's not an "integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry"

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, duplicates

When I do ->update() on my model, I get this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...
```

I know why and that's fine. What I want to achieve is that it does the update to all rows, except the ones where this constraint violation appears. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the query then to exclude your condition:

```
User::where('id', '!=', $request->id)->update($request->only('fields..'));
```

Here I use ID you will need to use the column that throws the exception with the value.

Comment: That is not possible unfortunately. I am changing an ID with `update()` and a complete other row already has that ID.